# Receive same JSON response as coming from server

Tags: iphone, ios

How to sort this json. The json below is output in browser.

```
{
event: {
July: [
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
}
],
Aug: [
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
}
],
Sept: [ ],
Oct: [ ],
Nov: [ ],
Dec: [
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
stamp: "1386019800"
},
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
stamp: "1387921620"
}
],
Jan: [ ],
Feb: [ ],
Mar: [ ], 
Apr: [ ],
May: [ ],
June: [ ]
}
}
```

Below is in console when fetched.

```
 Apr =     (
);
Aug =     (
            {

        createdSeatMap: "yes",
        status: "1",
        completed: "1",
        eventPayment: "0",
    }
);
Dec =     (
           {
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
stamp: "1386019800"
},
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
stamp: "1387921620"
}
);
Feb =     (
);
Jan =     (
);
July =     (
            {
        createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
    }
);
June =     (
);
Mar =     (
);
May =     (
);
Nov =     (
);
Oct =     (
);
Sept =     (
);
```

Below is code i am using

```
NSMutableArray *dictAllValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *getDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

getDataDict = [self.mGetDataDict valueForKey:@"event"];

NSArray *dictAllKeys = [[NSArray alloc] init];

dictAllKeys = [getDataDict allKeys];

NSLog(@"dict :%d", [dictAllKeys count]);
for(int i=0; i<[getDataDict count]; i++)
{
    NSString *strKey = [dictAllKeys objectAtIndex:i];
    [dictAllValues addObjectsFromArray:[getDataDict valueForKey:strKey]];
    if(i==0)
    {

        NSArray *cVals = [dictAllValues valueForKey:strKey];
        int c = [cVals count];
        NSLog(@"values:%@", cVals);
        NSLog(@"values:%@", dictAllValues);
        [self.mArrMOneEvents addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", c]];
        self.mArrMOneEtType = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"type"];
        self.mArrMOneEtTime = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"time"];
        self.mArrMOneEtSeatMap = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"createdSeatMap"];
        self.mArrMOneEtSeatId = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"seatMapId"];
        self.mArrMOneEtQuant = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"quantity"];
        self.mArrMOneEvents = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"eventName"];
        self.mArrMOneETLoc = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"location"];
        self.mArrMOneEtEId = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"id"];
        self.mArrMOneEtDesc = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"description"];
        self.mArrMOneEtDate = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"date"];
        self.mArrMOneEtCurr = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"currency"];
        self.mArrMOneEtCost = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"cost"];
        self.mArrMOneEtCateg = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"category"];
        self.mArrmOneEtImg = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"banner"];
        NSLog(@"array one:%d", [self.mArrMOneEvents count]);
    }
}
```

This is what i tried

```
NSArray *keys = [[getDataDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [keys count]];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    [array addObject: [getDataDict objectForKey: key]];
}
NSLog(@"array:%@", array);
```

Below is image describing the requirement of this.
[image]
Need response in same as way as coming from server, please guide for above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The server is returning a dictionary so there is no order. You mean you need to get the order from the JSON string of the response?

Comment: **One Question :** Why you want it in that order only ?

Comment: Asking the exact same question again is extremely bad form.

Comment: @Vin I have edited my question pls check, i need this because i am showing the twelve months of year starting from current month and each month may or may not have events in it. so table view is set month vise thus need json in sequence.

Comment: @borrrden i know that but just trying to get the answer, when i get my answer, will delete the other myself.

Answer (score 3):

A complicated way of sorting the keys of dictionary

```
NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];

NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
components.month = 1;

NSMutableArray *months = [@[] mutableCopy];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

[months addObject:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
while ([months count]<12){
    date = [calender dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
    [months addObject:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
}
//A sample dictionary to test
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"Jan": @"",
                             @"Feb": @"",
                             @"Mar": @"",
                             @"Apr": @"",
                             @"May": @"",
                             @"Jun": @"",
                             @"Jul": @"",
                             @"Aug": @"",
                             @"Sep": @"",
                             @"Oct": @"",
                             @"Nov": @"",
                             @"Dec": @""};

NSArray *keys = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                 ^NSComparisonResult(NSString * key1, NSString * key2) {
    NSUInteger index1 = [months indexOfObject:[key1 substringToIndex:3]];
    NSUInteger index2 = [months indexOfObject:[key2 substringToIndex:3]];
    return [@(index1) compare:@(index2)];
}];

NSLog(@"keys : %@",keys);
```

Comment: what to give in months static data or what didn't get.

Comment: @iPhone6 months is not static data, its dynamically formed. If current month is July. Order would be july to next year jun. If its oct, month would be oct-sep. The basic idea is to have a reference array. You would sort the keys based on it.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem for you is that your JSON Response is not properly formatted. There are many unwanted things in your JSON Response.
Look at Your JSON Response :

```
{
event: {
            July: [
                      {
                          createdSeatMap: "yes",
                          status: "1",
                          completed: "1",
                          eventPayment: "0",
                      }
                  ]
       }
}
```

In your case `event` should be an **Array of Events in different months**. Now in each Array you will have all the Events of that Month. Add the Key (in the above Example it is **"July"**) to the Array as a Value instead of making it a Key. See the Example of how your Response should look like :

```
{
event: {
            [
                  Month : "July",      <<--- //See this Line.
                  {
                       createdSeatMap: "yes",
                       status: "1",
                       completed: "1",
                       eventPayment: "0",
                  }
             ]
       }
}
```

As your server is returning a Dictionary , your Response will never going to maintain the order. You should modify your Response as described above from the Server Side.

Comment: you are right the format is not correct, but i have no good knowledge of php how to handle this what to covey to php developer.

Comment: @iPhone6: Just give them the Response I have added. If your response from the server formatted like this then your problem will be solved.

Comment: none of the above answer matched the requirement so,i made the change in JSON as per my requirement which changes the question completely. So neither can i post my own answer here and nor can accept any of above answer.

Comment: @iPhone6: That's what I suggested in my answer and that's why my answer is the most relevant.

Comment: i didn't made your change, in JSON somewhere month names are coming in full and somewhere in short so what i did was changed all the names to full name which then automatically fetches me sorted data.

Comment: Your answer just gave me the idea but not the solution. You tell how can i accept your answer is it fair to do so. What all i can do is upvote your post that i already did that time and thanks to you for your answer.

Comment: @iPhone6: I am not forcing you to "Accept" my Answer. I am just saying that if you have used my approach then also your problem was solved. So, my Answer is correct and that's why it should be accepted.